# i want to plot adc graph in realtime in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am very new to Qt programming and I want to plot an ADC value graph in real time. I read the ADC value continuously and I want to plot that in a graph. So how can I plot these values in a real time graph?

Comment: Please provide a lot more information before anyone will be able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at QWT (Qt Widgets for Technical applications).

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

In particular look at the examples with QwtSamplingThread which is designed for just this kind of application